# django connection.queries - 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

when i use connection.queries in django i get a weird exception:

```
'list' object is not callable
```

which isn't very clear to me. Here is the code i am running:

```
def myOtherFunction(request):
    return arrangeCountOfItems(Story.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).order_by('-create_date'))

def arrangeCountOfItems(storyList):
    for story in storyList:
        story.rateA = story.post_set.filter(rating=RATEA).count()
        story.rateB = story.post_set.filter(rating=RATEB).count()
        story.rateC = story.post_set.filter(rating=RATEC).count()
        print connection.queries()
    return storyList
```

i'm kinda trying to work out how to to filter by a foreign key's foreign key (something i'm also just about to ask here!) and thought i'd try to work out what is going on from the query... but no dice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connection.queries` is a list with SQL queries, it's not a callable function.

See [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) in the Django documentation for example. You can do the following instead:

```
print connection.queries
```